# 401 error with useParseQuery and back4app

Tags: react-native, parse-platform, back4app

I try to use back4end with a Parse server as the backend for my React Native app but can't manage to do a query.

I initialize Parse in the App.js :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Platform } from 'react-native'
import * as eva from '@eva-design/eva';
import { ApplicationProvider, IconRegistry } from '@ui-kitten/components';
import { EvaIconsPack } from '@ui-kitten/eva-icons';
import { AppNavigator, AuthNavigator } from './navigation';
import keys from './config/back4app';
import { initializeParse } from '@parse/react-native';
import UserContext from './config/context';

initializeParse(keys.serverURL, keys.applicationId, keys.javascriptKey);

export default () => {

    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        async function getCurrentUser() {
            if (user === null) {
                const currentUser = await Parse.User.currentAsync();
                if (currentUser !== null) {
                    setUser(currentUser);
                }
            }
        }
        getCurrentUser();
        setIsLoading(false);
      }, [user]);
  
    if (isLoading) {
        return null; // spinner
    }

    return(
        <UserContext.Provider value={user}>
            <IconRegistry icons={EvaIconsPack}/>
            <ApplicationProvider {...eva} theme={eva.light}>
                { user ? <AppNavigator/> : <AuthNavigator/> }
            </ApplicationProvider>
        </UserContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

And try to make a request in another screen (Feed.js) :

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import { Button, List, Text } from '@ui-kitten/components';
import { Page } from '../components/page';
import { Post } from '../components/post';
import { useParseQuery } from '@parse/react-native';
import UserContext from '../config/context';

export const FeedScreen = ({ navigation }) => {

    const user = useContext(UserContext);

    const parseQuery = new Parse.Query('Post');

    const {
      isLive, // Indicates that Parse Live Query is connected
      isLoading, // Indicates that the initial load is being processed
      isSyncing, // Indicates that the library is getting the latest data from Parse Server
      results, // Stores the current results
      count, // Stores the current results count
      error, // Stores any error
      reload // Function that can be used to reload the data
    } = useParseQuery(parseQuery);

    if (isLoading) {
        return <ActivityIndicator/>;
    }

    return (
        <Page navigation={navigation} title="Neurchi">
            <Text>welcome {user.get('username')}</Text>
            {error && (
                <Text>{error}</Text>
            )}
            <List
                style={styles.container}
                contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}
                data={results}
                renderItem={(info) => <Post item={info.item}/>}
            />
        </Page>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
    },
    contentContainer: {
      paddingHorizontal: 8,
      paddingVertical: 4,
    },
    item: {
      marginVertical: 4,
    },
  });
```

And I get this error :
`WebSocket connection to 'wss://parseapi.back4app.com/' failed: Unexpected response code: 401`

I tried to initialize Parse again in the other screen but didn't change anything. Also when I do a request in App.js it works ! So I guess it is problem of authorization...

Hope someone has an idea, thank you in advance !

Comment: I believe you need to activate Live Query. Could you please double check with this guide? https://www.back4app.com/docs/platform/parse-live-query

Comment: In addition to this, could you check to make sure your routing is set up properly? If you have everything directed towards your SPA, then this is the result you get. Explanation here: https://help.back4app.com/hc/en-us/articles/360031634031-Routing-Single-Page-Application-